# Get the sum of textbox fields value per row

Tags: php, jquery

I have here shopping cart using php. I add a script for getting the sum of all input fields. What I need to do is get the sum of all quarter per row. The problem is all of total fields gets the sum value of row. How I can get the sum per row?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.qtys').blur(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.qtys').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.qty_total').val(sum);
});
</script>

while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
<td><input type="text" name="product_qty" size="1" class="qty_total"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty1st" size="1" class="qtys"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty2nd" size="1" class="qtys"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty3rd" size="1" class="qtys"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty4th" size="1" class="qtys"/></td>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `$('.qty_total')` will give you call the elements having class `qty_total` but you need only one in the current row. Use the `qty_total` in the current row. You can get the parent row but `$(this).closest('tr')` then you can find the the `qty_total` using `find()`

Also use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each` instead of  `$('.qtys').each(function()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/yZefY/1/)**

Your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZefY/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.qtys').blur(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function() {   //.qtys of current row,
    sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum);     // total of current row
});
</script>
```

You need Quarter values of current row. `$(this).closest('tr')` gives you the `<tr>` parent of current `<td>`. So, the selector would update values of current row instead of all the rows which your previous code did.

All your operations need to work on current row being manipulated. **[.closest('tr')](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** helps in manipulating only the child elements of current row.

**Alternative** : `$(this).parents('tr')`

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to do it:

```
//gets the inputs in the correct row
$(this).parent('tr').children('.qtys').each(function(){

    //sums it
    totalSum=totalSum+$(this).val();

    //puts it in the total input
    $(this).parent('tr').children('td:nth-child(3)').children('input').val(totalSum);
});
```